# Debian process eating bandwidth like crazy... no go look for it

Tags: debian, bandwidth, process

I have a nice little headless Debian machine setup for small automated tasks.
But a few days ago i noted there is a big bandwidth RX on this one, more than the one predicted.
    I started **iftop** but now i only now to what ip's the bandwidth is coming from.
**Question:**
 *How can i find what process is taking up the most bandwidth on this debian machine ?*

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In relation to the netstat solution by lg:

Once you know the port that the data transfer is using, you can use the `lsof` tool to find out the process.

```
lsof -i :6753
```

The command is a lot easier to remember, but on the downside `lsof` isn't installed on all systems by default.

Answer (score 2):

With iftop, press p to view the port; then with `netstat -nutap | grep :PORT`. In the last column you can see the process name.

Answer (score 1):

Install [nethogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/), it's like top but for network bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the *port* used, you can figure out which daemon is using it. Alternatively, you can use `pktstat` to help. That shows you the port numbers.

Comment: so i found out the port (i think) what about finding out what process is using it ... ? :D